# How to find the number of black pixels which connect together in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, math

Assume I have a black and white picture. There are a few irregular shapes (black) on the picture (white background). I need to find out how many shapes in that picture and the size of each shape by counting the number of black pixel. Any easy way to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`bwconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) function. Assuming your image is stored as a binary matrix `img`:

```
CC = bwconncomp(img);
num = CC.numObjects;
sizes = cellfun(@length, CC.PixelIdxList);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `bwconncomp`? From the man page you linked: "The functions bwlabel, bwlabeln, and bwconncomp all compute connected components for binary images. bwconncomp replaces the use of bwlabel and bwlabeln. It uses significantly less memory and is sometimes faster than the other functions."

Comment: @Li-aungYip yes I suppose OP can use bwconncomp as well - I just suggested bwlabel because that's what I use. I wasn't aware of there being another option. Edited answer to use the newer function.